# Unable to execute PowerShell script from inside App Directory C#/.net Core

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, automation, runspace

I'm not quite sure why, but if I execute a script from a local folder outside my solution things run fine. When I call the file inside my project I get the following error:

```
System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException: 'AuthorizationManager check failed.'

Inner Exception
FileNotFoundException: C:\path\to\myproject\Modules\PSDiagnostics\PSDiagnostics.psm1
```

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
InitialSessionState _initialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
_initialSessionState.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;
//var script = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\MachineInfo.ps1";
var script = @"C:\scripts\MachineInfo.ps1";
using (var run = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(_initialSessionState))
{
    run.Open();
    var ps = PowerShell.Create(run);
    ps.AddCommand("Import-Module");
    ps.AddParameter("SkipEditionCheck");
    ps.AddArgument("CIMcmdlets");
    ps.Invoke();
    var err = run.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("error");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(err);//This will reveal any error loading
                
    ps.AddCommand(script);
    ps.AddArgument(Machine);
    var result = ps.Invoke();
    run.Close();
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why it only works if I call `script` externally (see the commented out line) from the project source? I'm setting MachineInfo.ps1 to Copy Always and Content (I've tried None too) for Build Action.

This is running via PowerShell 7 inside a C# WinUI 3 .NET Core app. PSDiagnostics.psm1 does not exist inside C:\scripts nor should it have to exist inside my app directory.

Comment: I have no explanation, but note that if your script is located in your application folder, use `AppContext.BaseDirectory`, not `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.  Also, `ps.Streams.Error` offers direct access to the (non-terminating) errors that occurred.

Comment: I ended up finding these modules in a different folder within my project: `runtimes\win\lib\net6.0\Modules`. Still doesn't quite make sense, my best guess is there is something within the PowerShell SDK that is dynamically choosing module locations based on the provided path. I copied those modules into the root of my project and all seems to be fine now. A band-aid, but it's fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a known issue, if you are building a self-contained application. The modules are not deployed into the publish folder correctly. See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15274

I fixed this by adding a build step that copies the modules into the correct place. There is a more sophisticated solution in the mentioned Github issue, I reduced it to a simpler build task since I am only targeting Windows.

```xml
<!--
Fix PS modules being in wrong place when publishing with a runtime identifier.
-->
<Target Name="PostPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PowerShellModules Include="$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)runtimes\win\lib\net6.0\Modules\**\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(PowerShellModules)" DestinationFiles="$(PublishDir)\Modules\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</Target>
```